# Orbeon: Static dropdown in repeated grid

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

I have a problem in repeated grid, I have a drop-down list where the users will choose what model they want.
Then I also have a JSON array which contains the model and other description of different cars.
How can I auto fill the appropriate JSON value to textField  according to the chosen value in the drop-down list?
Like for example: The user chose the model Toyota, only the Toyota car model present in the JSON will be displayed at textField.

The form I've created is available at https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/3b1ebd5340007f245b34ccd468c36c188b376bd6. And here is the JSON:

```
{
  "corppassUser": {
    "corppassData": null,
    "corppassEntity": {
      "primaryActiviyDesc": "Marine insurance ",
      "companyType": "A1",
      "corppassPreviousNames": [],
      "entityType": "LC",
      "primaryActivityCode": "65121",
      "businessExpiryDate": "",
      "secondaryActivityCode": "93202",
      "corppassShareholders": [
        {
          "allocation": 20000,
          "personRef": {
            "personName": "ANDY",
            "nationality": "SG",
            "id": 8,
            "idno": "S6001111A"
          },
          "currency": "SGD",
          "id": 3,
          "entityRef": null,
          "category": "1",
          "shareType": "1"
        },
        {
          "allocation": 10000,
          "personRef": {
            "personName": "TIMOTHY TAN",
            "nationality": "SP",
            "id": 6,
            "idno": "S1112374E "
          },
          "currency": "SGD",
          "id": 1,
          "entityRef": null,
          "category": "1",
          "shareType": "1"
        },
        {
          "allocation": 10000,
          "personRef": {
            "personName": "CLARISSA LIN",
            "nationality": "SG",
            "id": 7,
            "idno": "S3212386E"
          },
          "currency": "SGD",
          "id": 2,
          "entityRef": null,
          "category": "1",
          "shareType": "1"
        }
      ],
      "uen": "T15LP0005A"
    },
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me: I understand that you have repeated grid, and, say, in the first column you have a drop-down that allows users to select the model of a car. In your example the user selects Toyota. You then expect text fields on the same line to be filled based on the selected model and information in JSON. Could you give us an example of such a text field? Also, how are you planning to retrieve the JSON? Are you thinking of using an HTTP service?

Comment: Your form shows a country / state / city in rows of a repeated grid. Are you saying that you'd like to populate those dropdowns based on a single JSON that contains all the information for the country / state / city dropdown, and would like to load the JSON just once when the form loads? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Leo, did you get a chance to fill the dropdowns with JSON, or if still stuck have more per my earlier comment? ‑Alex